# Get last update time in a status history table for a given status

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I've this table
*order_status_history*, I insert a row everytime an order is updated, and let's say a table orders with only the column id:

| id | order_id | order_status_id | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 121 | ready | 2021-12-30 10:00:00 |
| 2 | 121 | shipped | 2021-12-30 10:01:00 |
| 3 | 121 | ready | 2021-12-30 10:02:00 |
| 4 | 121 | shipped | 2021-12-30 10:03:00 |
| 5 | 121 | delivered | 2021-12-30 10:04:00 |

I need to get the latest *updated_at* value for all the orders (DISTINCT) that have been *shipped* as last status, or *delivered* if for any reason there is no *shipped* status .

I wrote this query, but I get the last *updated_at* value of the *delivered* status. In the example case I need the *updated_at* as 10:03, but I get the 10:04 one.

```
SELECT o.id, 
       osh.max_updated_at AS updatedAt
FROM orders o
JOIN  ( SELECT order_id, 
               Max(updatedat) AS max_updated_at
        FROM   order_status_history
        WHERE  order_status_id IN('shipped','delivered')
        GROUP  BY order_id
      ) AS osh ON osh.order_id = o.id
AND ( SELECT order_status_id
      FROM order_status_history
      WHERE  order_id = o.id
      ORDER  BY updatedat DESC
      LIMIT 1 
     ) IN('shipped','delivered')
```

Comment: Can there be other statuses than shipped or delivered with later times than shipped or delivered for an order?

Comment: What does `select version();` show?

Comment: Yes, for example "cancelled". Or the order can back to the stock, so "ready"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one with subquery

```
SELECT id, (
  SELECT h.updated_at
  FROM order_status_history h
  WHERE h.order_id = o.id
  AND h.order_status_id IN ('shipped','delivered')
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM order_status_history k
    WHERE k.order_id = h.order_id
    AND k.updated_at > h.updated_at
    AND k.order_status_id NOT IN ('shipped','delivered')
  )
  ORDER BY CASE WHEN order_status_id = 'shipped' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC, updated_at DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS updatedAt
FROM orders o
```

Subquery works if you select a single column

This is another option for MySQL8+

```
WITH ordered AS (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY CASE WHEN order_status_id = 'shipped' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC, updated_at DESC) rn
  FROM order_status_history
  WHERE order_status_id IN ('shipped','delivered')
)
SELECT o.id, h.*
FROM orders o
LEFT JOIN ordered h ON o.id = h.order_id 
  AND h.rn = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM order_status_history k
    WHERE k.order_id = h.order_id
    AND k.updated_at > h.updated_at
    AND k.order_status_id NOT IN ('shipped','delivered')
  )
```

Comment: The subquery in my case did the trick